# Uncheck a group of check buttons

Tags: javascript, checkbox

I'm trying to uncheck a group of check buttons in an onclick event:

HTML:

```
 </div>
            <button onclick="getChart(); uncheck();" type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="refreshChart">Request</button>
        </div>

            <form class="form">
                <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified " data-toggle="buttons" name="chartSelect">
                    <label class="btn btn-info" id ="hide">
                        <input name="hide" type="checkbox" ><span>Hide</span>
                    </label>
                    <label class="btn btn-info">
                        <input name="total" id="total" type="checkbox">Total
                    </label>
                    <label class="btn btn-info">
                        <input name="max" id="max" type="checkbox">Max
                    </label>
                    <label class="btn btn-info">
                        <input name="mean" id="mean" type="checkbox">Mean
                    </label>
                    <label class="btn btn-info">
                        <input name="min" id="min" type="checkbox">Min
                    </label>
                    <label class="btn btn-info">
                        <input name="extrapo" id="extrapolation" type="checkbox">Extrapo
                    </label>
                    <label class="btn btn-info">
                        <input name="all" id="all" type="checkbox">All
                    </label>
                </div>
            </form>
```

I'm even just trying to just get one button to uncheck with no success.

JS:

```
function uncheck() {
    if ($('[name=max]').is(':checked')) {
        $('[name=max]').attr('checked', false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you precise which jQuery version you are using ? Seems there is different behavior between .attr and .prop on different versions http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Comment: I'm using `jquery:1.11.3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that calling filter `is` like this:

```
$("div[data-toggle='buttons'] input[type='checkbox']").is(":checked")
```

does not work. But if you put it with selector, it works. So this is fine:

```
$("div[data-toggle='buttons'] input[type='checkbox']:checked")
```

Now you can uncheck them all:

```
$("div[data-toggle='buttons'] input[type='checkbox']:checked").removeAttr("checked");
```

Try it in this <kbd>[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8f0ah6gz/)</kbd>

Comment: Still no dice, I have these buttons used in some `.change()` functions in another `js` file, could that be causing me issues?

Comment: Are you able to check code in `.change()` function? Yes it can be the cause for erratic behaviour. You can try to call your code after that function ends if possible.

Comment: No there is no way to check the code in the `.onChange()` function

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your code is working except that you have a call to a function `getChart()` that is not defined. When I remove that function call the checkbox is unchecked when clicking the button.

https://jsbin.com/yakiyopoye/edit?html,output

Comment: `getChart()` is defined, I've moved `unCheck()` form the ocClick event and put it at the top of `getChart()`, but it's not unchecking the box, I'm not sure why, i can see it works fine in your example...